# Debug shared plugin in console application in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, debugging, mingw, qt-creator, qtplugin

Greeting

I have 2 project in one session in qt creator. One is console application and the other is shared plugin. I'm loading the plugin and then call it's method. I want to enter plugin's method and debug it (like visual studio if you have projects in one solution). Is it possible? If it is, How can i do that?

```
QPluginLoader * pluginLoader = new QPluginLoader(pluginPath.c_str());
QObject * plugin = pluginLoader->instance();

if (plugin)
{
   deviceManager = qobject_cast<DeviceManager *>(plugin);
   return deviceManager->initialize();  //I want to enter this function which is in plugin project
}
else
{
   delete pluginLoader;
   return false;
}
```

PS: I'm using Qt 5.6.2 with MinGW 32bit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGW does not support this feature. I used Microsoft compiler instead.